# Angular - Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. Cannot read Blob array with FileReader

Tags: angular, typescript, blob

I try to get a list of byte arrays from backend and parse them to images in my Angular app.

Here's code for request to backend:

```js
public getImages(names: string[]) {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append("names", names.join(","));

    return this.httpClient.get<Blob[]>(API_URL + "diseases/images", {
      params: params,
    });
  }
```

And subscription code in component:

```js
  getImages(names: string[]) {
    this.encyclopedyService.getImages(names).subscribe((data: Blob[]) => {
      let image: SafeUrl = null;
      console.log(data);
      data.forEach((bytes) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(bytes);
        reader.onload = (e) => (
          (this.imageBytes = reader.result),
          (image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.imageBytes))
        );
        console.log(image);
      });
    });
  }
```

And everytime I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
> at _global.. [as readAsDataURL]

Blockquote

Comment: Can you check if the `bytes` is valid inside the `forEach` statement?

Comment: Just add responsetype to get request: {
      params: params, responseType: 'blob' 
    }

Comment: But how can I access the array elements inside if I add responseType: 'blob'?